# Authorization check in Blade Template

Tags: laravel

I need to control access to the menu items.  Here is the Gate Function that is created inside AuthServiceProvider. How do I access it inside a blade template

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
  Gate::define('isAdmin',function($user){
        return $user->type === 'admin';
    });

    Gate::define('isGeneralUser',function($user){
        return $user->type === 'user';
    });

    Gate::define('isPaidUser',function($user){
        return $user->type === 'paid';
    });
    Gate::define('isSubscriber',function($user){
        return $user->type === 'subscriber';
    });
```

**Menu**

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="hvr-sweep-to-right" href="{{route('weekly-trades')}}">Weekly Trades</a></li>
    <li><a class="hvr-sweep-to-right" href="{{route('daily-trade')}}">Daily Trades</a></li>
    <li><a class="hvr-sweep-to-right" href="{{route('videos-articles-archive')}}">Videos & Articles Archive</a></li>
    <li><a class="hvr-sweep-to-right" href="{{route('blog-list')}}">Surplus forex Blogs</a>
    </li>

</ul>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Not sure that would be a correct use-case for Gates. @Nikola has a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create the `if blade directives` and show the routes for each role you have, like this:

```
Blade::if('isRole', function ($role) {
    return Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === $role;
});
```

Then in your blade template you can filter routes like so:

```
@isRole('agent')
    // Agent routes
@elseisRole('admin')
    // Admin routes
@else
    // Other routes
@endisRole
```

P.S: I assumed you want to show routes for the logged in user

EDIT: You actually created `Gates` which restrict any users to do the given action, it doesn't mean you restricted them access to pages necessarily. You just said that `admin` users can't do `isAdmin` action, which doesn't make much sense :)

Update: For checking multiple roles you can change your `Blade::if` to accept an array of `roles` instead of a single one:

```
Blade::if('isRole', function ($roles = []) {
    if (empty($roles) || !Auth::check()) {
        return false;
    }

    return in_array(Auth::user()->type, $roles);
});
```

Then you can use the directive as:

```
@isRole(['agent', 'admin'])
    // User is either agent or admin
@elseisRole(['admin'])
    // User is admin
@else
    // User is something else
@endisRole
```

Comment: Where to declare it blade directives

Comment: Instead of your `Gate` code inside `AuthServiceProvider`, use the `Blade::if...` code

Comment: How do I check @isRole('user' or 'admin')

Comment: Updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

however, it is late but it is useful for someone, here what you want to just admin see write inside the condition

```
@can('isAdmin')
    <!-- The Current User is admin -->
@endcan
```